# how to speed up pandas (query the dict ) in this case?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict named buy_groups that stores a set of SessionIDs, then I want to see the element of dataframe SesssionData has a SessionID appearing in the dict. If it exists, then I set Buy as 1. The data frame is like this

```
SessionID Buy    
1          0
2          0
3          0
```

For instance, if 3 exists in the dict buy_groups, then I set the related buy=1.

I write a vectorized version like this

```
SessionData.Buy[SessionData.SessionID.apply(lambda x: buy_groups.has_key(x))== True] = 1
```

It takes about 5 seconds.

Instead,the iteration takes even shorter time, like 2 seconds,

```
for items in keys_value:
    if buy_groups.has_key(items)== True:
        SessionData.loc[SessionData['SessionID']==items,'Buy'] = 1
```

How can I speed up this operation since both dataframe and dict are very large.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused about exactly what you want.  All you want to do is to set 'Buy` to 1 for all SessionIDs which are keys in buy_groups? Or for all SessionIDs which are (1) keys in buy_groups and (2) also in keys_value (whatever that is)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want set the 'Buy' to 1,  for all SessionIDs which are keys in buy_groups.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Per Andy Hayden suggestion, I changed buy_groups.keys() to buy_groups to avoid the unnecessary list conversion.

Here's what I would try.  It uses a boolean index approach

```
rowindex = SessionData['SessionID'].isin(buy_groups)    
SessionData[rowindex,'Buy'] = 1
```

Comment: You can drop the .keys(), in python 2 this creates a list unnecessarily (which has to then be converted into a set).

Comment: Thanks a lot,  Bob and Andy. I will try it out.